# The origins of the SOC in silicene

Tags: condensed-matter, graphene, spin-orbit

I read that silicene has a stronger SOC than graphene. As far as I know the SOC ~ $Z^4$. Thus, since silicon lies further in the periodic table, it explains why it has a stronger SOC than graphene. But are there other origins or grounds of the stronger SOC in silicene than in graphene?